# How to remove HTML text from my text files

Tags: python, html, loops, variables

I need to remove HTML from my text file

This is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://psalmboek.nl/zingen.php?psID='
psalm = 1
url3 = '&psvID='
vers = 1
url5 = '#psvs'

end_psalm = 150
end_vers = 10
```

I found this variable but i dont know how to place it into my loop

```
def remove_html_tags(text):
    """Remove html tags from a string"""
    import re
    clean = re.compile('<.*?>')
    return re.sub(clean, '', text)
```

Is it also possible to psalm += 1 so it will repeat till the 150th psalter?

```
while vers != end_vers:

    response = requests.get(url + str(psalm) + url3 + str(vers) + url5)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    soup.findAll('p')
    one_a_tag = soup.findAll('p')[0]
    f = open("psalm"+str(psalm)+"_"+"vers"+str(vers) +  ".txt","w+")
    f.write(str(one_a_tag))
    f.close
    vers += 1
    print (vers)
```

So i need to remove every HTML code what comes from one_a_tag

Comment: "Is it also possible to psalm += 1 so it will repeat till the 150th psalter?" -> That would be possible. But please take good care that your requests are not mistaken for a unholy denial-of-service attack.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you can try this code:

```
    f.write(re.sub(re.compile('<.*?>'), '', str(one_a_tag)))
```

Comment: My code isn't understaning the re.sub and re.compile

Comment: Update: I imported re and it worked. Thank you very much. now i need something that can see when to go to the next psalter